# What are the numbers in the square brackets in NSLog() output?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nslog

What is the stuff between the `[]` in the log message below? I get this in my iPhone app, and I have no idea where the message is coming from. My first guess would be a line number, but which file would it be in?

```
2010-10-19 08:56:12.006 Encore[376:6907]
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The first number is the process ID, the second is the logging thread's Mach port. A desktop example:

```
2010-10-19 17:37:13.189 nc_init[28617:a0f] nc <CFNotificationCenter 0x10010d170 [0x7fff70d96f20]> - default <CFNotificationCenter 0x10010d2a0 [0x7fff70d96f20]>

(gdb) i thread
Thread 1 has current state "WAITING"
    Mach port #0xa0f (gdb port #0x4203)
    frame 0: main () at nc_init.m:10
    pthread ID: 0x7fff70ebfc20
    system-wide unique thread id: 0x167b49
    dispatch queue name: "com.apple.main-thread"
    dispatch queue flags: 0x0
    total user time: 13232000
    total system time: 16099000
    scaled cpu usage percentage: 0
    scheduling policy in effect: 0x1
    run state: 0x3 (WAITING)
    flags: 0x0
    number of seconds that thread has slept: 0
    current priority: 31
    max priority: 63
    suspend count: 0.

(gdb) p/x (int)mach_thread_self()
$1 = 0xa0f
```

Notice how 0xa0f is reported as the thread's Mach port.

Answer (score 2):

first number is the process ID, unsure about second, this line will precede every line thats printed to console from your application.

Possibly a `NSLog(@"");` is causing this.

Is your application running or has it crashed by this stage?

Comment: My application is running just fine at this point. The rest of the log message was complaining about a NSData instance being autoreleased without a pool, so the system was printing it out. I was just trying to figure out where the message was coming from, but I figured it out just now.

Answer (score 1):

The first number is the process ID, as the others have said. The second number is the thread ID, at least I'm pretty sure that's what it is...

Answer (score 0):

It's a process ID in fact. You can see that in the GDB console with a line somewhere that should read "[Switching to process 376]".