# Numbers Against Project Name in Log Texts iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, logging, nslog

I really need to know what does the numbers against project name in log texts means.
For Example:

```
2013-04-24  12:00:00:000  ProjectName[xxxxx:xxx]  Some Log Text
```

here [xxxxx:xxx] is some number which I need to know about..

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968679/what-are-the-numbers-in-the-square-brackets-in-nslog-output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one is **Process ID** and Second one is **Thread ID**.

```
xxxxx = Process ID
xxx   = Thread ID.
```

Answer (score 0):

these are the thread id and thread port
explained even clearly on the following post

[What are the numbers in the square brackets in NSLog() output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968679/what-are-the-numbers-in-the-square-brackets-in-nslog-output)